# Helping understand quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hi i have a problem concerning finding quotient rings in general. 
Let's have $R=Z[x]$ and it's ideal $I=(x^2+2)\cdot Z[x]$ how should i find $Z[x]/I$? It's elements are cosets of $R$. So i need to take element from ring that doesn't belong to ideal and add it to $I$, and for another i add element that doesn't belong to $0+I$ and newly created $a+I$ and until i have whole $R$? And how it will look like in this example?
Will be very glad for help i am newbie so thorough explanation are more than welcome :)

Comment: The article [How to work with quotient rings](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwi8pcSUkbjKAhVLvRoKHZsgC7cQFgg7MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mtts.org.in%2Fuserapps%2Fdownload-expo.php%3Ffileid%3D84&usg=AFQjCNExQ92RAE0eC0O7BBGkGAPMIUabYw&sig2=oYElUfsassd4IQP0SVDPiA) is helpful, I think.

Comment: That link is broken. Try instead https://www.scribd.com/document/212434698/How-to-Work-With-Quotient-Rings.

Answer (score 1):

This one is fairly simple, keep in mind that for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ we have that
$$a \cong b \implies a-b\in I$$
This means can use the smallest possible values and for our polynomials they'll be of degree less than 2. Why? Think like we have $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, multiply our $x^2+2$ by $ax$ and we get $ax^3+2ax$, subtract these and we get $bx^2+(c-2a)x+d$, we do again multiply $x^2+2$ by $b$, getting $bx^2+2b$ and subtracting from our previous result we get $(c-2a)x+(d-2b)$, this means we have that
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d-((c-2a)x+(d-2b))=(ax+b)(x^2+2)\in I$$
and as such they are equivalent (if the first coefficient in the ideal was NOT $1$ it'd be different and you make have the degrees being equal and not just less than)

so we have all elements come in the form of $ax+b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$. Now we know how the elements look like in their simplest form, we don't really care for anything else. However is this isomorphic to anything? Mayhaps $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{2}]$, I'll leave that to figure on.